# Ionic1 bottom navigation over modal

Tags: ionic-framework

I have bottom navigation visible on all screens, when I change screens using ui-router, my bottom navigation bar stays visible but when I push a `$ionicModal`, it overrides my bottom navigation bar. Is there any css tricks for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the ionic's modal css.
add a class to modal div:

```
<div class="modal bottom-navigation">
Modal Content here
</div>
```

and add the following css to that

```
div.modal.bottom-navigation{
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  min-height: unset;
}
```

Check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mjyGdy) for working example:

Comment: this answer looks awesome, thank you fro this but my bottom navigation also has a big button at  the center, I have to show that button over modal too ._.

Comment: is the button outside of the nav tab? if so just increase the decrease the height of `.bottom-navigation`.

Comment: Temporarily fixed this position as creating bottom navigation a component and putting this component in modal views. so it's not stupid if it works :D